# Query for the same time period of every day in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to query for a metric on a specific hour of every day as a data table. I am new to Prometheus and not sure if it's even possible.

The end result I am looking for is something like this:

```
Average hourly latency for the month of April

Hour | Average Latency
---- | ---------------
12AM | 123.4
1AM  | 156.7
...
```

Is it possible and if so how to achieve that?

Comment: I initially misunderstood your question, so I posted an irrelevant answer. You basically want to 'strip' the date out of a timestamp and aggregate over samples based on their time. I don't think that's currently possible, as the timestamp manipulation functions such as `offset 1d` do not allow loops over wider time ranges (eg 2 weeks).